# Unable to get a While Loop with function is not working with onclick() function

Tags: javascript, html

Unable to get a While Loop with function is not working with onclick() function. This is the HTML code with the JavaScript function:-

I would like a test a While Loop function, where I enter a random name in a text field and click the Show Me and the resulting output - each letter of the full name should appear vertically downwards in a column. However, when I click the onclick function, there is no output result.

```js
function verticalFullName() {
  var fullname = document.getElementById("fullname").value
  if (fullname == "") { //Fred Smith
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Please input a name.";
  } else {

    var i = 0;
    while (i < fullname.length) {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += fullname[i] + "<br>";
      i++; //i = i + 1  
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td class="label_col">Full Name:</td>
  <td class="input_col"><input name="fullname" id="output" type="text" onblur="verticalFullName();"></td>
</tr>
<button onclick="verticalFullName()">Show me</button>

<p id="fullname"></p>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("fullname").value` refers to your paragraph, not the input

Comment: like @j08691 said, so change your `getElementById("fullname")` to `getElementById("output")` or change your switch your ID / Name on your element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input id is "output" not "fullname"

You have the input field name="fullname" and id="output"

Your best solution is probably to swap the id of fullname and output though to get the desired result!

```
<tr>
  <td class="label_col">Full Name:</td>
  <td class="input_col"><input name="fullname" id="fullname" type="text" onblur="verticalFullName();"></td>
</tr>
<button onclick="verticalFullName()">Show me</button>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: your solution worked! I have one question, when I click the onclick button, it produces two "Fred Smith" names vertically. What is the cause of the duplicate full name - Fred Smith?

Comment: Yup. That's because of your onblur and button click. Clicking a button activates onclick and onblur for the text field.